# Android- Create tabs inside fragment without v4 support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am trying to create a 'tabs' w/o using support library for my application, but I didn't find even a simple working example/tutorial  anywhere.

Since my entire application is using `android.app.fragment`, so I cannot change all of the existing `fragments` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Creating a tab within fragment using support library is a piece of cake, but I am wondering whether we can create one w/o `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Hey bro, you can try my answer below. I have already test and it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved, it's easily, follow my step:

1.Copy the offical source code of `FragmentTabHost` to your project, and change following 3 class refrence:
`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`  to  `android.app.Fragment`
`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`  to  `android.app.FragmentManager`
`android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` to `android.app.FragmentTransaction`

2.Use the modify version of your `FragmentTabHost` in project, and forget the `android.support.v4` library. My edited version: [FragmentTabHost](https://gist.github.com/codezjx/20116b5b61fcab07a231)

Sample code: (Show the first tab, after 5 sec delay, you will see the second tab, I run on my Android Studio successfully!)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getFragmentManager(), R.id.container);

        // Add each tab
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("first"), BlankFragment1.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("second"), BlankFragment2.class, null);


        mTabHost.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("second");
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.bill.myapplication.FragmentTabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabhost">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.bill.myapplication.FragmentTabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Bill, I want to create tabs inside fragment, not activity(you create it inside MainActivity). However, I use the same approach

Comment: You can use the modify version of "FragmentTabHost" everywhere, my sample just use Activity. You can use Fragment also, just replace getFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: Looks like your approach 1 works. Please refer my gist. https://gist.github.com/ritesh-nitw/6555cf681c17770b7737

Only concern that I have is a warning: 
Call requires API Level 17(Current min is: 15) android.app.fragment#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: So I think that is why Google create the support-v4 library, it's design for older platform. If you really want to create tabs in Fragment, I strongly recommend you use the offical version of FragmentTabHost.Just need to change the relevant reference of "android.app.fragment" but not the logic code. It's quite simple. Good luck, bro!

Comment: Yup I understand. Thanks for help! Appreciated!! Although I could not find the solution that I was expecting, awarding the bounties for showing me the right path.

Comment: Did you found the solution @ritesh_NITW ? Using the official version of FragmentTabHost with "android.app.fragment" does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put the fragments inside tab content in your layout XML and add them to the `TabHost` in `onCreate`.